# Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate on GKE for WSO2 API Management

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, wso2-api-manager, nginx-ingress

[image]

I encourage an issue regarding setup the TLS Cert-Manager Controller on GKE for WSO2 API Management.

---

I am using WSO2 product Docker images available from WSO2 Private Docker Registry, following the Helm Chart for the deployment of WSO2 API Manager with WSO2 API Manager Analytics on Github ([README](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/README.md)). And I successfully deployed the WSO2 API Manager with Nginx Ingress Controller ([deploy-a-nginx-ingress-and-a-certitificate-manager-controller-on-gke](https://medium.com/bluekiri/deploy-a-nginx-ingress-and-a-certitificate-manager-controller-on-gke-using-helm-3-8e2802b979ec)).

---

I want to create a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform using an Nginx Ingress Controller to integrate with a certificate manager to automate the process of issue and renew the required certificates.

---

I easily replicate the TLS Cert-Manager Controller on GKE for HelloWorld example from the same medium tutorial ([deploy-a-nginx-ingress-and-a-certitificate-manager-controller-on-gke](https://medium.com/bluekiri/deploy-a-nginx-ingress-and-a-certitificate-manager-controller-on-gke-using-helm-3-8e2802b979ec)).

[image]

**hello-app-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-production
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/issuer":"letsencrypt-production","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect":"true"},"name":"hello-app-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"test.japangly.xyz","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"hello-app","servicePort":8080},"path":"/helloworld"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["test.japangly.xyz"],"secretName":"test-japangly-xyz-tls"}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-30T04:27:12Z"
  generation: 3
  name: hello-app-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "6478"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/hello-app-ingress
  uid: ea2d8b13-e9b6-4cb0-873d-76ed40253e4f
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.japangly.xyz
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /helloworld
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.japangly.xyz
    secretName: test-japangly-xyz-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.239.145.46
```

However, not working the WSO2 API Management, all I get is

> Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate

[image]

**wso2am-pattern-1-am-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-production
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: wso2am-pattern-1
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: wso2-apim
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-30T04:41:10Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: wso2am-pattern-1-am-ingress
  namespace: wso2-apim
  resourceVersion: "88840"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/wso2-apim/ingresses/wso2am-pattern-1-am-ingress
  uid: 58f4b549-a565-493b-9f9f-72ad76877819
spec:
  rules:
  - host: am.japangly.xyz
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wso2am-pattern-1-am-service
          servicePort: 9443
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - am.japangly.xyz
    secretName: am-japangly-xyz-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.239.145.46
```

Comment: I ran setup like yours and noticed that the `cert-manager` was creating the secret but was not provisioning it further. `Issuer` is namespaced resource and needs to be in namespace where your `Ingress` resides. Please tell if your namespace `wso2-apim` have the `Issuer` needed to provide the certificate. For troubleshooting you can run `$ kubectl describe certificate -n namespace`. Also the fake Kubernetes certificate is used when there is an issue with a `tls: secret` part.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment:

> I ran setup like yours and noticed that the `cert-manager` was creating the secret but was not provisioning it further. `Issuer` is namespaced resource and needs to be in namespace where your `Ingress` resides. Please tell if your namespace `wso2-apim` have the `Issuer` needed to provide the certificate. For troubleshooting you can run `$ kubectl describe certificate -n namespace`. Also the fake Kubernetes certificate is used when there is an issue with a `tls: secret` part.

I wanted to give more insight on what the potential issue may be and some other tips working with `nginx-ingress`.

---

Certificate showing as `Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate` will kick in when there are issues with the actual secret storing the certificate used in the `Ingress` definition.

One of the possible situations where `Fake Certificate` will kick in is in the lack of the actual secret with a certificate.

---

As pointed in the part of my comment, `Issuer` is a namespaced resource and it needs to be in a namespace that `Ingress` and `secret` is created. It will create a `secret` but it will not progress further with signing.

Looking on your setup:

- `nginx-ingress` controller spawned in `nginx` namespace (**GOOD**)
- `cert-manager` spawned in namespace `cert-manager` namespace (**GOOD**)
- `Issuer` for certificates spawned in `default` namespace (**POTENTIAL ISSUE**)
- `WSO2` application spawned in `wso2-apim` namespace (**POTENTIAL ISSUE**)

To make it work you can either:

- Run your `WSO2` application in `default` namespace same as `Issuer`
- Create an `Issuer` in `wso2-apim` namespace
- Create a [ClusterIssuer](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/reference/clusterissuers.html)

As pointed by official documentation:

> An `Issuer` is a namespaced resource, and it is not possible to issue certificates from an `Issuer` in a different namespace. This means you will need to create an `Issuer` in each namespace you wish to obtain `Certificates` in.
>
> *[Cert-manager.io: Docs: Concepts: Issuer](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/)*

---

As for troubleshooting steps you can invoke following commands:

- `$ kubectl describe issuer ISSUER_NAME -n namespace`
- `$ kubectl describe certificate CERTIFICATE_NAME -n namespace`
- `$ kubectl describe secret SECRET_NAME -n namespace`

---

Assuming that:

- You have a working Kubernetes cluster
- You have spawned `nginx-ingress` and have the `LoadBalancer IP` provisioned correctly
- You have a domain name pointing to the `LoadBalancer IP` of your `nginx-ingress` controller

After that you spawned:

- `example` namespace
- `hello-app` as in medium guide:

  - `$ kubectl create deployment hello-app --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 -n example`
- exposed it locally

  - `$ kubectl expose deployment hello-app --type=NodePort --port=8080 -n example`
- created an `Ingress` resource like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - super.example.com
    secretName: super-example-tls
  rules:
  - host: super.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
```

With no `Issuer` in the `example` namespace the logs from the certificate will look like that:

- `$ kubectl describe certificate super-example-tls -n example`

```yaml
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    6m33s  cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  6m33s  cert-manager  Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "super-example-tls-XXXXX"
  Normal  Requested  6m33s  cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "super-example-tls-XXXXX"
```

`Issuer.yaml` used in an example for more reference:

```yaml
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: example
spec: 
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: PUT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

After you create an `Issuer` you should see a new event in `certificate`:

```yaml
  Normal  Issuing    25s    cert-manager  The certificate has been successfully issued
```